# Querying database by using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a question related to a side project that I am currently attempting to finish.  I've been searching everywhere for this, but my main issue is to include a dynamic drop down box that queries the database as the user types.  For example, when a user types the word letter 'a' everything will appear with that word and so on and so forth.  I created a small database using SQL Server 2005 and created a simple website for my project.
Basically, I I need it to query the server and store the results.  This has been my main issue and do not know where to proceed.  This article that I found could possibly do the trick by using AJAX [LINK](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/01/27/asp-net-4-0-and-ajax-tutorial/)

Here is the image of what my website plans to execute:
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=d6ff3b929e0ca913&id=D6FF3B929E0CA913!126&sff=1&v=3

I want to start with something simple, like making a connection string first to ensure there is connectivity between my website and SQL server.  Afterwards, then I would start implementing the autocomplete feature.  Do you have any other tips/suggestions as to where I should start with something basic and working my way up?

Comment: Seach about [jQuery autocomplete](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-UI-AutoComplete-TextBox-with-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx). I guess thats the one your looking for.

Comment: use a ajax toolkit combobox or autocomlete plugins like @stuart said

Comment: Try using JQueryUI, using the Auto Complete feature.. see 
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use microsoft auto complete textbox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the list to use as the custom source.  
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(new string[]
                    {
                        "January",
                        "February",
                        "March",
                        "April",
                        "May",
                        "June",
                        "July",
                        "August",
                        "September",
                        "October",
                        "November",
                        "December"
                    });

    // Create and initialize the text box. 
    var textBox = new TextBox
                  {
                      AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                      AutoCompleteMode = 
                          AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                      AutoCompleteSource =
                          AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                      Location = new Point(20, 20),
                      Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                      Visible = true
                  };

    // Add the text box to the form.
    Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

You can change source with your data selected from database.I hope ,it will be useful for you.